# Print issue for SharePoint list forms

Tags: list, list-view, printing

When I am trying to print the **SharePoint Online list form**, column header values are repeating in print preview. Of course in print also header values are repeating. How to print the OOB SharePoint list without having any issue? I am trying in Google Chrome
[image]